# Why do I get SKPaymentTransactionState.restored when purchasing a renewable subscription

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

Trying to figure out the exact flow for IAP. Read a lot about it but there are a couple elements I couldn't explain yet. I do on-device validation (I know, not the best, but in my case it is :)).

- Why do I get SKPaymentTransactionState.**restored** when **purchasing** a monthly renewable subscription? The previous purchase has correctly expired (environment: Sandbox, 30+ minutes after purchase)
- How to handle this restore message?
- Renewals: Will the app receive a transaction in updatedTransactions (paymentQueue) when the renewal happens? Or do I have to refresh the receipt when the current period is expired?
- Change of purchase plan: What if a user purchases a yearly sub, then downgrades to a monthly sub? Should I refresh receipt to know about it?

Comment: Also having the same issue. Did you find any answer/solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this the restored state is valid, however, inside the `latest_receipt_info` object will have changed and you need to look for the `purchase_date` and `original_purchase_date` as well as `expires_date` to handle your app logic. The transaction id will have also changed incase you have any server side logic that determines if the receipt is valid.